# error in using search in jsp

Tags: jsp, search

I'm working on a jsp page that the user can browse through collection of movies by using a search form that allows him to search by category, title, or release dyear. If there is not any search condition, all movies should be displayed.
my problem is that only **the search by release year works fine, but searching by title not working and it just displays nothing with no results**searching by title works when I put it at the bottom of the year search doesn't work, and Vice versa

```
 <% 

         String s1 = request.getParameter("Ttl");
         String s2 = request.getParameter("Yr");

       out.println("<TABLE >");
      out.println("<TR>");
      out.println("<TH>Category</TH>");
      out.println("<TH>Title</TH>");
      out.println("<TH>Release Year</TH>");
      out.println("<TH>Rental Price</TH>");
      out.println(" <TH></TH>");
      out.println("<TH></TH>");
      out.println(" </TR>");

          String sql = //search if no search condition
        "SELECT *" +
        " FROM users" +
        " WHERE ";

          if (s1!=null && !(s1.equals(""))){ //search by title 
                       sql =  sql +
        "title LIKE '%" +
        s1 + "%'";
                                             } 
              if (s2!=null){                   //search by year
                       sql =  sql +
        " year LIKE '%" +
        s2 + "%'";
                                             }  



     try{  
  Connection con =
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:UsersData");
      System.out.println("got connection");

    Statement s = con.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql);                
      while (rs.next()) {
          out.println("<TR>");
       String id = rs.getString(5);
        out.println("<TD>" + rs.getString(1) + "</TD>");
        out.println("<TD>" +    rs.getString(2) + "</TD>");
        out.println("<TD>" +  rs.getString(3) + "</TD>");
        out.println("<TD>" + rs.getString(4) + "</TD>");
       out.println("<TD><A HREF=Add to shoping cart?id=" + id + ">Add to shoping cart</A></TD>");
        out.println("</TR>");
      }
      s.close();
      con.close();
    }

    catch (SQLException e) {
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
    %>
```

Comment: Suggestion: print out the SQL string, and compare the "working" vs "non-working" cases.

Comment: Eeeew, scriptlets, even for the table stuff?! Yuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a condition in your SQL, like an `OR`.

More importantly, even if you *must* use a scriptlet in JSP, this is a poor way to go about doing it: the HTML should be just that, HTML; there's absolutely no reason to be doing that in the scriptlet too.

Comment: @AliDeV I don't understand. If you want to make a conditional query, your query should have a conditional in it.

Comment: What you need, AliDev to have is something like "... where title like '%xxx%' OR year like '%xxx%', but you're missing the keyword "OR".  (It's what I was pointing out in my answer below, too.)  (+1 for "don't use a scriptlet", btw.  And it should be a prepared statement, too.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you searching by BOTH year and title?  If so, I don't see an "AND" in between those two conditional clauses.

Comment: searching by title works when I put it at the bottom of the year, and Vice versa

Comment: In that case, there's no "OR" in the query either.